# vg not assigned to the pv group

Tags: volume, redhat-satellite

this is the picture [image: vgmissing]
I would like to know how to make same vg assigned to the pv vda4

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/173368)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the existing VG with the following command:

```
# vgextend rhel_p460a28 /dev/vda4
```